# How to get the encoding correct when reading the redirected output stream of another process

Tags: c#, character-encoding, async-await

I am launching another process (node.exe) in order to capture its output and display it in my own Winforms window. The idea is that I'll be able to automatically restart the process if the node server crashes. The code included is just test code, not final code, and it does not kill the process so if you run it, you'll need to *kill the node process manually* after closing the form.

My problem is that although I am correctly redirecting the output and error streams, there are some funny characters that don't display on the normal console. How do I change it to correctly detect the encoding and display properly?

Here's a sample of output (with some garbage characters at the beginning of each string).

```
[32m[2014-11-26 08:24:21.525] [INFO] console - [39mExpress server listening on port 8080
```

Here's the code to launch the process, and redirect the output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AHVMonitor
{
    enum Output
    {
        StandardOutput,
        StandardError
    }

    public sealed class ProcessWatcher
    {
        private ConcurrentQueue<string> logLines = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        private Process process;
        private string arguments = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Arguments"];
        private string filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Filename"];

        public IList<string> Log
        {
            get { return logLines.ToArray(); }
        }

        public async Task<bool> WatchAsync()
        {
            Func<Task<bool>> waitForProcess = async () =>
            {
                var result = false;
                process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);

                // Hide the (empty) console window, since we are redirecting the output.
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                process.Start();

                await TaskExtensions.ForAsync(0, 3, 3, async i =>
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            await RedirectStandardErrorOrOutputAsync(Output.StandardOutput);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            await RedirectStandardErrorOrOutputAsync(Output.StandardError);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            result = await Task.Run(() =>
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    process.WaitForExit();
                                    return process.ExitCode == 0;
                                }
                                catch { return false; }
                                finally
                                {
                                    process.Dispose();
                                    process = null;
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                    }
                });
                return result;
            };
            return await waitForProcess();
        }

        private async Task RedirectStandardErrorOrOutputAsync(Output outputType)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(outputType == Output.StandardError ? process.StandardError.BaseStream : process.StandardOutput.BaseStream))
            {
                var line = string.Empty;

                while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                    logLines.Enqueue(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For that code to work, you need these two extensions for my *ForAsync* on the 3 Tasks. (wraps a *ForEachAsync* implementation not written by me.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AHVMonitor
{
    public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        #region IEnumerable<T>.ForEachAsync and IEnumerable<T>.ForAsync

        /// <summary>A ForEachAsync implementation. Based on a sample in an article by Stephen Toub,
        /// <a href="http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx">
        /// Implementing a simple ForEachAsync, part 2</a>.</summary>
        public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int maxDegreeOfParallelism, Func<T, Task> body)
        {
            return Task.WhenAll(
                from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(maxDegreeOfParallelism)
                select Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    using (partition)
                        while (partition.MoveNext())
                            await body(partition.Current);
                }));
        }

        /// <summary>An asynchronous ForAsync implementation.</summary>
        /// <remarks>It simply creates an <b>Enumerable.Range</b> and wraps <b>ForEachAsync</b>.</remarks>
        public static Task ForAsync(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive, int maxDegreeOfParallelism, Func<int, Task> body)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(
                fromInclusive, toExclusive).
                ForEachAsync(maxDegreeOfParallelism, async i => await body(i));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The code of the form that uses the "ProcessWatcher", which contains only a button and a textbox, is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AHVMonitor
{
    public partial class WatcherForm : Form
    {
        private ProcessWatcher watcher = new ProcessWatcher();

        public WatcherForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WatcherForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LogAsync();
        }

        private async void LogAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1D));
                var lines = watcher.Log;
                logTextBox.Lines = lines.ToArray();
                logTextBox.SelectionStart = logTextBox.TextLength;
                logTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }

        private async void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await watcher.WatchAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing the standardoutput from a single thread and seeing what the result is?

Comment: Not yet. I can have a go and see what happens. This code is based on some more complex code I wrote long ago that wraps ffmpeg, and its output came out fine from multiple threads, so I doubt that the threading is an issue.

Comment: Are you sure those "junk values" aren't coming out from the `StandardError`?

Comment: Pretty sure it has to be a text encoding issue. I just copied this from the console window on live server: [2014-11-26 11:14:20.858] [INFO] [default] - User jasoncf1 logged in.

Comment: So it appears that those characters only come through when I copy the stream. I have tried specifying the encoding explicitly when creating the StreamReader, as well as passing a 'true' parameter for it to detect the encoding, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "garbage" looks like [escape codes for setting colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), missing the unprintable character ESC (0x1B).

Comment: You're right. (The missing character simply didn't copy and paste well here.) I meant to update this question or answer it myself, but that is indeed where the characters come from. Since I am not setting colours in my application, the solution was simply to replace those characters as I find them in the log.